# Alter SQL statement for queries in MS ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm familiar that you can change tables using the ALTER TABLE statement. Is there a way to do the same for queries e.g. ALTER QUERY? I'm trying to change a field name from Expr1 to "MeaningfulFooNameField".

Something along the lines of:

```
"ALTER QUERY qryFoo RENAME COLUMN Expr1 to MeaningfulFooNameField;"
```

I can't do this manually as there are hundreds of tables to go through to keep the data definition consistent.

Comment: Just change the query definition. Go to the design of the query and change the name.

Comment: The problem with changing the name in design mode is that it doesn't seem to update other dependencies on the changes?

Comment: By other dependencies you mean like form fields and that sort of thing? Those will NOT update automatically, you will have to edit those too.

Comment: There is nothing like `ALTER QUERY ... RENAME COLUMN` available in Access SQL.  Actually Access SQL doesn't even support `RENAME COLUMN` for a table.

Comment: But aren't you actually wanting to change an alias for a field expression within multiple saved queries?

Comment: @HansUp duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/q/30760842/2679750

Comment: @MarkC.  Similar at least.  But both confuse me enough that I can't say whether they're the same.

Comment: It sounds like someone never renamed field expressions to something meaningful and kept them as the default (Exp1, Exp2), and now they desire for them to all be changed, which is just not possible aside from doing it manually, per query/form.